# Sagepay payment gateway integration for Eshop (Wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress, opayo

I have a site which is using the [Eshop plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/eshop/) for Wordpress.

My client requires to take payments using [Sagepay](https://www.sagepay.com/), this options is not available to set within the plugin.

I cannot seem to find any extension plugins to enable this feature, I would write my own but do not know much PHP.

I have found a '[template](http://quirm.net/wiki/eshop/additional-plugins-and-code-snippets/adding-a-merchant-gateway/)' for custom payment gateways which Eshop have provided. Is it possible to use this to extend Eshop to use Sagepay? Alternatively do you know of a plugin for this?

Note: I understand this may be off topic, but I would not ask if I was not in real need. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Which integration is your customer willing to use? The easier to integrate is FORM but you have DIRECT and SERVER as well.

Regards,

Pablo

Comment: Hey Pablo, I think FORM sounds like the best approach for this website. I should be able to integrate the form elements into the plugin [template](http://quirm.net/wiki/eshop/additional-plugins-and-code-snippets/adding-a-merchant-gateway/) that I have. I just need guidance on how to do so.